# Why is the following about logarithms true?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I was reading some algorithm's analysis and I came across the following in the proof:

$\log_2(n+1) \le h \le 1 + \log_2(n) \implies h = \lceil \log_2(n+1)\rceil$

Here both $h$ and $n$  are integral. Why is the above true ?

Comment: Should the logarithm on the right be logarithm base 2?

Comment: yes ! thanks for noticing

Comment: Hint: $log_2(n)<log_2(n+1)$  So $log_2(n)<h\leq 1+log_2(n)$.  How many different integers $h$ can be in the range $(x,x+1]$ for any real number $x$?  And is $\lceil \log_2(n+1)\rceil$ in that range when $x=log_2(n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ceiling function $\lceil x\rceil$ can be defined as the unique integer in the interval $[x,x+1)$.
But $1+\log_2(n)< 1+\log_2(n+1)$, so $h$ is an integer in the interval $[\log_2(n+1),1+\log_2(n+1))$.  That means that $h=\lceil \log_2(n+1)\rceil$.